# wp_ajax_ actions that use object-oriented action handlers?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, namespaces, include

I'm trying to pass an ajax action to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, however I can't seem to get it to call any functions that use a class to encapsulate the namespace. I get the following error:

```
Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'PHP_faq_backend' not found in /wp-includes/plugin.php
```

My action is as follows:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_edit_form', array('PHP_faq_backend', 'edit_form'));
```

Obviously I don't want to force this by modifying the admin-ajax.php file, but how do I get my classfiles loaded so the action will work?

Comment: include them with your plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are including your class files somewhere within your Wordpress theme (functions.php), or Plugin.

I usually use something like this;

```
<?php
class Some_Class {

    public function __construct() {
        //logged in users
        add_action('wp_ajax_some_method', array($this,'some_method'));
        //non logged in users
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_some_method', array($this,'some_method'));
    }

    public function some_method(){
        //check nonce values etc
        if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['some_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['some_nonce'], 'class_some_nonce' ) ) {
            wp_die(__('Naughty', 'some-class-textdomain'));
        }

        //proceed with post data validation - then execute method
    }

}

$some_class_instance = new Some_Class();
?>
```

The above is for registering actions from within a class instance.

Comment: I was using an OO approach with multiple classes and this particular classfile was not being included when I was expecting. Took a bit of debugging but solved it. Thanks for the suggestions - this is a solid example of how wp_ajax_ calls should look in an OO plugin!

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the error message is your first clue. I've had this same issue on multiple versions of WP. In some environments, the installation won't recognize third-party classes. There's a couple things you can probably do to try to resolve this:

1. Check the permissions on your class files to see if you have sufficient rights
2. Check that your classes are being loaded, e.g. explicitly include them in your functions.php file (not an ideal or recommended method)

The one solution that I have found always worked is this:

1. Create a skeleton plugin that you need to activate through the Plugins manager
2. Your plugin file should include all the classes you want to work with.
3. Activate your plugin. Done.

This approach can be accomplished in a couple different ways; the first is that you can define a plugin directory that resides in your current theme directory -- this lets you keep all of your files together; the second is to go the normal route and create a plugin folder under `wp-content/plugins/my-skeleton-plugin`. Here's a skeleton plugin to get you started if you go through with this approach:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Skeleton Plugin Base
Plugin URI: http://www.yourdomain.com
Description: This is a base plugin to use as a template for other plugins.
Author: Author Name
Version: v0.0.1
Author URI: http://www.yourdomain.com
*/

    # +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    # PLUGIN URL AND PATH CONSTANTS
    # +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    /**
     * Don't depend on WP to always provide a consistent directory/path to use.
     * Extrapolate one the location of this file. The reason for this is that some
     * themes might re-locate the plugins and themes directory to another folder
     * and therefore break the normal WP structure.
     */
    define( DS, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, true );

    $PLUGIN_URL = WP_PLUGIN_URL . DS . str_replace( basename( __FILE__ ),'', plugin_basename(__FILE__) ); 
    $PLUGIN_DIR = dirname(__FILE__);

    define( MY_PLUGIN_URL, $PLUGIN_URL, true );
    define( MY_PLUGIN_DIR, $PLUGIN_DIR, true );


    # +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    # INCLUDES
    # +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    /**
     * Include the plugin.
     */
    // Use include() if you prefe
    include_once( MY_PLUGIN_DIR . '/inc/classes/my_skeleton_plugin.class.php' );

    try
    {

        /**
         * Initialize the plugin
         */

    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        throw $e;
    }
```